# React app using Cloudflare Pages: error react-scripts@5.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cloudflare, cloudflare-pages

When I deploy a React app using Cloudflare Pages, the `Building application` step fails with the error:

```
error react-scripts@5.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.0.0". Got "12.18.0"
error Found incompatible module.
```

There is no such error when running `yarn build` or `yarn run start` on my local machine.

How can this error be fixed?

My `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "foobar",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.8.8",
      "@emotion/react": "^11",
      "@emotion/styled": "^11",
      "@supabase/supabase-js": "^1.33.3",
      "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
      "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
      "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
      "axios": "^0.26.1",
      "framer-motion": "^5",
      "react": "^18.0.0",
      "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
      "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
      "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
      "extends": [
        "react-app",
        "react-app/jest"
      ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
      "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
      ],
      "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

I once encountered this problem and I was able to fix it by specifying the `NODE_VERSION` environment variable.

In your case, set the environment variable as shown below:

`NODE_VERSION` = 14.0.0